# Items are not getting onclick method in viewpager adapter

Tags: android

I have added two fragments into viewpager adapter ..inside that i have added only one button with simple toast ...onclick methods are not triggering

i have set clickable,focussable all attributes in xml nothing works.

setting up viewpager adapter

```
        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter=new 
        ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),contactModels);
        viewPager=findViewById(R.id.loc_viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Viewpager Adapter

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter

 {

    private static final String TAG = "ViewPagerAdapter";
ArrayList<ContactModel> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,ArrayList<ContactModel> arrayList ) {
        super(fm);
        this.arrayList=arrayList;
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment selectedFragment=null;
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0:
                selectedFragment=ListOfContacts.newInstance(arrayList);
                break;
            case 1:
                selectedFragment= DueList.getInstance();
                break;



        }

        return selectedFragment;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String s=null;
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                s="List of contacts";
                break;
            case 1:
                s="Due list";
                break;



        }

        return s;
    }
}
```

Viewpager xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/account_circle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline15"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline16"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.45" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline17"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline15" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline17"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/loc_viewPager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My Duelist fragment adding some onclick methods

```
public class DueList extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "DueList";

    Button button;

    public static DueList getInstance()
    {
        DueList dueList=new DueList();
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        dueList.setArguments(bundle);
        return dueList;
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View  view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_due_list, container, false);
        button=view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: ");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Due list xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not be sure that the view is already inflated in `onCreateView`.

Try setting the clickListener in `onViewCreated()`

Answer (score 0):

Try to first get view pager adapter which fragment load after that fragment inside get click event ..
add this two method into viewpager adapter..

```
 fun getCurrentFragment(): Fragment? {
    return mCurrentFragment
}

override fun setPrimaryItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) {
    if (getCurrentFragment() !== `object`) {
        mCurrentFragment = `object` as Fragment
    }
    super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, `object`)

}
```

after that get fragment when you used viewpager like..

```
fun addProductCart() {
    var fragment = categoryPagerAdapter.getCurrentFragment()
    if (fragment is ProductListFragment) {
        fragment.addProductIntoCart() // here perform fragment inside any action..
    }

}
```

Comment: i dont know kotlin can u say in java